# Migrating from windows-1252 to UTF-8 character set

Tags: oracle, migration

I'm thinking of migrating my database (oracle) from windows-1252 to UTF-8 by doing the following:

- export all data (backup)
- truncate all tables
- run `alter database character set`
- import data back

Is there a way to detect if any characters will be lost or need manual adjustments before the migration?

- If so, how?
- If not, then how to prevent losing characters during the migration?

Comment: **Do not** run `alter database character set`, it is deprecated since Oracle 10.1, you may destroy your database. Follow the [Character Set Migration Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch11charsetmig.htm#NLSPG011) and/or use the [Database Migration Assistant for Unicode Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E71288_01/DUMAG/toc.htm)

Comment: If you consider to truncate all data and import all data afterwards, then it might be easier to create a new fresh database and import all data into there.

Comment: I agree with Wernfried. Better just create a new fresh database.